# Collect data from multiple table from database and facing problem to show that data in blade

Tags: laravel

I'm new to laravel. I'm collecting data from three database table for a logged-in user.

```
$Employee = Employee::where("id", $id)->get();
$Salary = Salary::where("emp_id", $id)->get();
$SalaryDetails = SalaryDetails::where("emp_id", $id)->get();
$data = array(
    'Employee'      => $Employee,
    'Salary'        => $Salary,
    'SalaryDetails' => $SalaryDetails
);
return view('pages.manager.salaryDetails')->with($data);
```

When I send those data to the blade it says

```
Property ... does not exist on this collection instance.
```

Here if I use `foreach` the problem is solved. The problem arises when I call it by `{{$Employee->fullname}}`. I don't want to use `foreach` here because I'm collecting data for one single user. Is there any way to show data in the blade without using `foreach`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get single user use `find` instead of `get`:

```php
$Employee = Employee::find($id);
```

When you use `where` to filter some data and then getting it via `get` method, you will get a collection. In your case you will get collection with one `Employee`.

In that case you can also do like that:

```php
$Employee = Employee::where("id", $id)->first();
```

Method `first` returns first element in collection.